# Настроить nginx с react-router, чтобы сервер возвращал ошибку 404

Tags: nginx, react-router, http-status-code-404

Сайт реализован на React с react-router-dom, на сервере настроен nginx, c location / {
try_files $uri /index.html;
}
То есть при запросе любой страницы, даже несуществующей отдается index.html, соответственно, если страница не существует дальше происходит перенаправление на страницу site.ru/page404. Но код ответа сервера 200. Как это исправить? Возможно ли сделать, чтобы код ответа сервера был 404, так как это рекомендуется для seo оптимизации